# C++ constexpr constructor initializes garbage values

Tags: c++, c++17

I wanted a simple class which would encapsulate a pointer and a size, like C++20's `std::span` will be, I think. I am using C++ (g++ 11.2.1 to be precise)

I want it so I can have some constant, module-level data arrays without having to calculate the size of each one.

However my implementation 'works' only sometimes, dependent on the optimization flags and compiler (I tried on godbolt). Hence, I've made a mistake. How do I do this correctly?

Here is the implementation plus a test program which prints out the number of elements (which is always correct) and the elements (which is usually wrong)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class CArray {
 public:
  template <size_t S>
  constexpr CArray(const int (&e)[S]) : els(&e[0]), sz(S) {}
  const int* begin() const { return els; }
  const int* end() const { return els + sz; }
private:
  const int* els;
  size_t sz;
};
const CArray gbl_arr{{3,2,1}};

int main() {
  CArray arr{{1,2,3}};
  cout << "Global size: " << std::distance(gbl_arr.begin(), gbl_arr.end()) << endl;
  for (auto i : gbl_arr) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  cout << "Local size: " << std::distance(arr.begin(), arr.end()) << endl;
  for (auto i : arr) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Global size: 3
32765
0
0
Local size: 3
1
2
3
```

In this case the 'local' variable is correct, but the 'global' is not, should be 3,2,1.

Comment: Both `const CArray gbl_arr{{3,2,1}};` and `CArray arr{{1,2,3}};` create a temporary c-array, the address of which is used to initialise `CArray::els`.  The temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression leaving dangling pointes and UB.

Comment: It is a good idea to run the code with sanitizers - [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oTTj6cazP) correctly produces errors. (Although the debugging info seems to be missing).

Comment: @Quimby that's a good point, I did try with various -W options but not -fsanitize=. However not sure I would have figured out what I was doing wrong from those errors

Comment: @PeterHull Yea, the stack trace is usually better, not sure why it is not the case here. Good options are `leak,undefined,address`; `thread`; and `memory` which is clang-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is your initialization is creating a temporary and then you're storing a pointer to that array after it has been destroyed.

```
const CArray gbl_arr{{3,2,1}};
```

When invoking the above constructor, the argument passed in is created just for the call itself, but gbl_arr refers to it after its life has ended.  Change to this:

```
int gbl_arrdata[]{3,2,1};
const CArray gbl_arr{gbl_arrdaya};
```

And it should work, because the array it refers to now has the same lifetime scope as the object that refers to it.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Is there a way to do it in a 'one-liner', without the extra variable, do you think?

Comment: @PeterHull No, I don't think so.  At least, not in a way that is acceptable.  On second thought, I did come up with one way but I don't think you'll like it.  I don't.  :) `const CArray gbl_arr{[]()->int(&)[3]{static int x[]{1,2,3}; return x;}()};
`

Comment: You're right, I do not like that! I am surprised, since all the info is there at compile-time, I would have thought there'd be some constexpr wizardry to do it.